# Fortran Application Timing .f90

Tags: fortran, command, timing

```
!////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
!   Timing Program
!   usage:
!           ./program -nt T
!           T:   number of iterations to run for (default = 1000)
!
!   description:
!           Computes a[1:nx] = -a[1:nx] T times, for array length nx (= 10256)
!           Reports time
!           Reports time per interation
program main
    use iso_fortran_env, only : output_unit, real64

    implicit none

    !//////////////////////////////
    ! Timing variables
    integer :: t1, t2, count_rate, count_max, i, j
    real(real64)  :: elapsed_time

    integer, parameter :: opu=output_unit
    real(real64), allocatable :: a(:)
    real(real64), allocatable :: b(:)
    real(real64), allocatable :: c(:)
    real(real64), allocatable :: r(:)

    !~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    !   Problem Control Parameters
    integer :: niter = 1000
    integer :: nx = 10256
    !~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    call grab_args(niter)
    call grab_args(nx)
    allocate(a(nx))
    allocate(b(nx))
    allocate(c(nx))
    allocate(r)
  
    a(1:nx) = 1.0
    b(1:nx) = 2.0
    c(1:nx) = 5.0
 
    r = a * b + c

    write(opu,*)'looping ', niter,' times.'
    write(opu,*)'points', nx, 'count em'
    call system_clock(t1, count_rate, count_max)
    do j = 1, niter
       do i = 1, nx
          r(i) = -a(i)
       enddo
    enddo

    call system_clock(t2, count_rate, count_max)
    elapsed_time = real(t2-t1) / real(count_rate)

    write(opu,*)'Elapsed time: ', elapsed_time
    write(opu,*)'Elapsed time per iteration: ', elapsed_time / niter

    deallocate(a)
    deallocate(b)
    deallocate(c)
    deallocate(r)

contains

    subroutine grab_args(numiter)
      implicit none

      integer, intent(inout)   :: numiter

      integer :: n                    ! Number of command-line arguments
      integer :: i
      character(len=1024) :: argname  ! Argument key
      character(len=1024) :: val      ! Argument value

      n = command_argument_count()
      do i=1,n,2
         call get_command_argument(i, argname)
         call get_command_argument(i+1, val)
         select case(argname)
         case('-nt')
            read(val, '(i8)') numiter
         case('-nx')
            read(val, '(i8)') nx
         case default
            write(output_unit,'(a)') ' '
            write(output_unit,'(a)') &
                 ' Unrecognized option: '// trim(argname)
         end select
      enddo

  end subroutine grab_args


end program main
```

Comment: I second PierU's comment. It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: The script is supposed to time high performance computing.  The command line variables control the number of points and the number if iterations.  I have made a mistake with respect to number of points, nx, but I cannot figure out what it is.  Thank you for being patient with me.

Comment: How do you expect `nx` to be read if you don't specify a variable into which the value is put? `read(val, '(i8)')` is missing a variable: `read(val, '(i8)' <somevariable>)`

Comment: read(val, '(i8) nx)   let me try that

Comment: that helped but something is still broken.  it looks like it stops running before it even starts

Comment: it looks like i broke it so that it reads one input for both command line variables and ignores the other one. i can't see how i could've done that though

Comment: Why is the original declaration of `nx` commented out? The repeated call to `grab_args` does not make sense to me. The internals of that subroutine look like it should be called just once but that  both `nx` and `numiter` should be accessible at the same time.

Comment: that's one of the parts where i got confused.  I need to make sure that I correctly initialized my arrays to be one dimensional, double-precision arrays of length `nx`, where `nx` is your defined command-line argument for the size of the arrays.

Comment: The currently posted code does not compile.

Comment: Sure: you have edited the posted code that was producing the compilation error, just after my comment. Which is good, but don't pretend it was compiling then. EOT for me.

Comment: thank you for helping everyone.  I am editing the original source code again.  it looks like my only problem

Comment: I am so lost.  I can completely lost.  I might just start over from scratch...

Comment: You cannot just post code. You must ask a question. Please read [ask].